# What does “cock-back“ mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

The phrase “cock-back“ is used in Eminem's song 'Phenomenal' :

> “...feel like you want to hit that wall, then do it, punch through it, just **cock-back**, put your all into it“

What does this phrase mean?

Comment: Wouldn't that be weird in this context? The message this song conveys is all about not giving up and moving forwards.

Comment: Draw your fist back so you are ready to strike a blow. Parallel to pulling the hammer back on a handgun so you are ready to pull the trigger to fire a shot.

Comment: Your link has an extra *e* on the end.

Comment: Here it is again: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cock%20back

Comment: I think you can include the first comment in the question and delete the second one. Deadrat's comment answers your question. Think about a cock's head and imagine how it moves **back** and forth.

Answer (score -1):

guns. it is cocking back a gun.

Comment: Actually I don't think it is; you can "cock back" your fist in preparation for a punch, and given that it mentions hitting and punching immediately before, it's pretty evident to me that it does mean your fist.